# AVD error when trying to run within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-4.1

why is it that I can run my avd as a separate window but not within the application in android studio?
I'm running the latest version of everything.
[Here is a picture of my avd as a standalone application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxB5g.png)

This is what the console prints out when I try to run it with the avd within android studio.

```
11/15 22:10:25: Launching 'app' on No Devices.
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 was killed.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Update Worked for me. Thank you.